# reCaptcha cannot stop looping on Android Webview

Tags: android, loops, webview, recaptcha

I'm glad to join this community! and I'd like to begin making an interesting question,

I'm trying to watch a video on waaw.tv (Russian) and after passing DDos controls, appears a reCaptcha, and when I complete succesfully the code, appears again, as a looping. What I have to do on my WebView (Java, Android) to get rid of this reCaptcha once done?

Thanks you very much

Comment: @M. Mariscal Have you found the solution?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, for some reason reCAPTCHA (at least Google's version 2) needs local storage enabled. We managed to solve the issue by using

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

I remove `webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(...)` and everything works well